# Time difference in R by group based on condition and two time columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I would like to get the time elapsed between events in my dataframe, for each grouping of data by the ID. The dates i want to use are in their own columns. I have done the following already using dplyr:

- Grouped my data by the ID
- Ordered by the ID

This is how the data looks. I would like the output to be the time_diff column. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
ID: Status:    Start-time:   End-time:    time-diff:
1   Active      01/01/2018       NA           0
1   Complete      NA         01/02/2018       1
2   Active      03/02/2018                    0
2   Active        NA                          0
2   Complete      NA         03/06/2018       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the time difference between a time and a `NA` value will just return `NA`. A more meaningful approach would be to take the individual time different of each event, and then summarize over each group (`id`).

```
d <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2),
            st = ymd(c("2019-05-03", "2019-02-06", "2019-07-11","2019-05-13")),
            et = ymd(c("2019-05-10", "2019-02-16", "2019-07-04","2019-05-09")))

d2 <- d %>% 
  mutate(td  = et-st,         # calculate the time difference (td)
         atd = abs(td)) %>%   # calculate the absolute td (atd)
d2

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id st         et         td      atd    
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <time>  <time> 
1     1 2019-05-03 2019-05-10  7 days  7 days
2     1 2019-02-06 2019-02-16 10 days 10 days
3     2 2019-07-11 2019-07-04 -7 days  7 days
4     2 2019-05-13 2019-05-09 -4 days  4 days
```

Then you can take the mean of the absolute differences for example and get:

```
d2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%            # for each group (id)
  summarise(mtd = mean(atd))  # calculate the mean time difference (mtd)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id mtd     
  <dbl> <time>  
1     1 8.5 days
2     2 5.5 days
```